# How to go to another directory sharing same parent directory?

Tags: linux, directory, ls

I am beginner in linux and wondering about a shorter way to go a directory having same parent directory. Here I elaborate that.

```
dir1
    - dir11
    - dir12
    - dir13
    - dir14
```

Directory `dir1` has sub-directories `dir11,...,dir14`. I am at directory `dir13` and want to go to `dir12`. What is direct way to do this?

I can do

```
cd..
cd dir12/
```

But I am wondering whether I can do this in single step. Any ideas?

Comment: You can do `cd ../dir12`.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` doesn't only take one directory to change to. You can provide a complete path to which you want to go.

You can simply type `cd ../dir12`
You can also go all nuts with `cd ../dir12/../dir13/../dir14/..`

Try also the following: type `cd ..<press Tag twice>`. This will list you all directories in the path you have given.

There are wildcards that `cd` can use. For example `~` is your home directory. `cd ~` or just `cd` will change into your `$HOME`.

See `man cd` (in a terminal) for more.